# In java socket programming chat application, Is it possible to create a individual chat for each clients like whatsapp?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, client-server, serversocket

Now I'm done with the application which have the server and client, server accepts the client request and add the client object into the Arraylist and starts a new thread for each clients. when multiple clients connects, clients can list all the clients, and they can send a message to any clients in the list. For example client1, client2, client3 connects to the server client1 and client2 sending a message to the client3,It will be printed in client3 console. all working fine. Now i need to add additional feature that each clients sends a message in individual chat, if client1 opens a chat with client2 the conversation between those two clients only should be displayed, not client3 messages, and vice versa. To do that implementation do i need any additional concept like multi threading. I'm not asking a source code, I'm just asking a idea to implement the above feature.

**Can anyone tell me the suggestion or reference to implement separate chats for different clients... Need to keep the old messages until the server goes offline?**

**Server.java**

```
package server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Server {
    static Vector<ClientHandler> AllClients = new Vector<ClientHandler>();
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1111);
            System.out.println("Server Started");
            while(true) {
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                String clientname = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Connected With : "+clientname);
                ClientHandler client = new ClientHandler(s,clientname);
                Thread t = new Thread(client);
                AllClients.add(client);
                t.start();
                System.out.println("Ready to accept connections...");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

**ClientHandler.java**

```
package server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClientHandler extends Thread{

    private DataInputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private String ClientName;
    private boolean login;
    private Socket Socket;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    ClientHandler(Socket s,String name) throws Exception{
        this.in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        this.out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        this.login = true;
        this.ClientName = name;
        this.Socket = s;
    }
    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            try {
                String received = in.readUTF();
                if(received.equalsIgnoreCase("logout")) {
                    this.login = false;
                    this.out.writeUTF("logout");
                    int i;
                    for(i = 0; i < Server.AllClients.size(); i++) {
                        if(this.ClientName.equals(Server.AllClients.get(i).ClientName))
                            break;
                    }
                    Server.AllClients.remove(i);
                    System.out.println(this.ClientName+" logged out");
                    this.Socket.close();
                    break;
                }
                if(received.equalsIgnoreCase("getlist")) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < Server.AllClients.size(); i++) {
                        out.writeUTF(i+1 +", "+Server.AllClients.get(i).ClientName);
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                if(received.contains(",")) {
                    String[] Message = received.split(",");
                    for(ClientHandler c : Server.AllClients) {
                        if(c.ClientName.equalsIgnoreCase(Message[1]) && c.login) {
                            c.out.writeUTF(this.ClientName +" : "+ Message[0]);
                            c.out.flush();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error :"+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        try {
            this.in.close();
            this.out.close();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
package client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    static DataInputStream dis;
    static DataOutputStream dos;
    static Socket s;
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Cient Name : ");
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            s = new Socket("localhost",1111);
            dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeUTF(name);
                Thread sendMessage = new Thread(new Runnable()  
                { 
                    @Override
                    public void run() { 
                        while (true) { 

                            String msg = sc.nextLine(); 

                            try {
                                dos.writeUTF(msg);
                                if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("logout")) {
                                    System.out.println("Logged out");
                                    break;
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) { 
                                System.out.println("Error in send method :"+e.toString());
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                }); 


                Thread readMessage = new Thread(new Runnable()  
                { 
                    @Override
                    public void run() { 

                        while (true) { 
                            try {
                                String msg = dis.readUTF();
                                if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("logout")) {
                                    System.out.println("Logged out");
                                    break;
                                }
                                System.out.println(msg);

                            } catch (IOException e) { 

                                System.out.println("Error in read method :"+e.getMessage());
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                }); 

                sendMessage.start(); 
                readMessage.start(); 


    }


}
```

If my code have any irrelevant statements please do suggest a better way to optimise the code

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is: yes it is possible.

The second answer: it's not about threading, you have to think in the first place (it's important, but not in the frist place).

the third answer: as i understand your code, the main data-structre is the collection of clients and their handler. In my opinion there is a further abstraction-layer missing in between.
In the frist place think about a data structure like "chatRoom". A client connecting to server has to send a "chatRoom"-name to the the server. Than the server creates the chatRoom or adds the client to the chatRooom's client-set. From that point a client can send his messages to the chatRoom not to the client directly anymore.
In a further step: To enable sending messages to inidividual clients you can e.g. enforce a chatRoom for every pair of clients (take care: this can be very expansive), so individual communication between clients is still possible.

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain in detail about chatRoom, what it is?

Comment: just think about something like a phone-conference or a skype meeting. People can join or leave a conference or a skype chat. So your Chatroom needs  `register(Client c)` and `unregister(Client c)` methods, that allow entering or leaving the chatRoom. Registered clients all are stored in a `Collection<Client> registeredClients`. Now you only need a `postMessage(String msg)`-Method, a client can call on every chatroom, the client is registered in. This method loops over every client of the collection and sends the `msg` to the client, so every client receives the msg.